# How to read large files?

Tags: vb.net

The challenge I'm faced with is this - I read the contents of files and put them into one single file that will be unpacked eventually. It works fine, but when amount of data that is larger than the amount of free memory it runs out of it. I've fixed this by writing the data as soon as the file is read. However, to read the big files data and unpack it I can't read it all at once, so I have to read it line by line in stream reader, I just can't rack my mind around how I should insert the data in a way that's easy to differentiate between where files start and stop, and pull them out once I'm trying to do so.

I appreciate any insight!

Comment: This is not clear at all - "how I should insert the data in a way that's easy to differentiate between where files start and stop, and pull them out once I'm trying to do so"

Comment: Basically I read the file bytes, convert them to base 64 etc, then write them to a file, back to back, but are seperated by a character sequence. If I could read the whole file at once I could look for this seperater and from there split the data, but i have to read it line by line.

Comment: Do you really need to write base64 into file? This increases size you fighting. Second thing, you can create a header in which you allocate specific number of bytes to save size of your next file. This way you know that you read 8 bytes to get the size, then read specified number of bytes , which will be the file bytes.

Comment: That sounds intereting, could you perhaps provide a link that has an example of the headers?

Comment: :) I think you can google

Comment: Everything that comes up is for C Headers, not the type you speak of, which you seem to know more about than me, thats why I ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82391/discussion-between-killpot-and-t-s).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176790/reading-multiple-files-in-a-stream

Comment: you should post some of the code; there are lots of XY candidates in that description

Comment: What is file? - a string of bytes or array of bytes. If you agree with yourself that first 8 bytes you will use to only store info on the length of the following file, all you have to do is - read 8 bytes and get the number of bytes to read(after first 8). Then read that number of bytes. Now, you located right at beginning of next sequence. Repeat until no more bytes.